# Batch convert mono WAV to stereo verbatim

Tags: unix, batch, wav, mono, stereo

I have a bunch mono .wav files which I need to convert to stereo in order to run thru lame.
Lame can't encode stereo mp3s from mono input so that's what I need to do.

I don't need any modifications to the data made other than duplicating channel into two.

I've tried to use `sox` and it seems to alter sound data in eerie ways by up-downsampling and changing bit depths in between as well as running filters I don't need.

So please recommend me some tool to batch convert .wav files from mono to stereo.
I'm on linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sox input.wav output.wav channels 2
```

Comment: sox doesn't do verbatim conversion, it applies numerous transforms and filters (in your case, for example, dither - look up `-D`; but god knows what else)

Comment: Uh, no. With only `channels` it either duplicates or downmixes unless the format has to be changed for some reason.
`$ sox -V ...`
`sox INFO sox: effects chain: input        48000Hz  1 channels`
`sox INFO sox: effects chain: channels     48000Hz  2 channels`
`sox INFO sox: effects chain: output       48000Hz  2 channels`

Comment: Not works on linux arch